# Making <li> styling using bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have one text that needed to looks like this:

[image: bootstrap li styling]

The problem with this that when i use bootstrap 3 common classes like this

```
   <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
   </ul>
```

That number gets inside li, and i dont need that, i need in bootstrap 3 to seperate that number, see the picture, but to keep shemantic to be like in normal order in `<li>` element.

Here is working  fiddle what i have for now
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7187/

**EDIT update full answer**

**CSS**
          ol.list-numbered {
            counter-reset: subsection;
        }

```
   ol.list-numbered {
        counter-increment: section 3;
        list-style: none;
    }

    ol.list-numbered li::before {
        counter-increment: subsection;
        content: counter(section) "." counter(subsection) " ";
        margin-left: -30px;
        width: 30px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
 <ol class="list-numbered">                
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis nisi vitae est porta aliquet. Nullam lacinia ornare diam, in lobortis massa eleifend a. Phasellus tempor lacus ligula.. </li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis nisi vitae est porta aliquet. Nullam lacinia ornare diam, in lobortis massa eleifend a. Phasellus tempor lacus ligula.. </li> 
 </ol>
```

Comment: I created edit, if someone can create answer based on my edit, but just add heading , and i will accepted it

Comment: I don't know how it does Bootstrap, but the correct approach is to use `OL` instead of `UL` and `list-style-position: outside`. See the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ov5f4rwf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified [Panther](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1595669/panther)'s [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29960336/2020820) using your original fiddle to show how you can do what you want with what he said:

```
ol.list-unstyled {
    counter-reset:section 3;
}

ol.list-unstyled > li {
    list-style:none;
}

ol.list-numbered {
    counter-reset:subsection;
}

ol.list-numbered li::before {
    counter-increment:subsection;
    content:counter(section) "." counter(subsection) " ";
}
```

demonstrated in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/daiopowen/DTcHh/7215/) which has been updated to be valid HTML5 markup.

Comment: Nice added just styling, the problem is that this HTML is not valid HTML5 markup :( Txanks

Comment: I've fixed that issue now.

Answer (score 2):

Remove classes from the list (we want to show `list-style`, not to hide them as Bootstrap do), and use ordered list `<ol>` instead of unordered `<ul>`.

```
<style>
    ol {
       counter-reset: section;
       list-style-type: none;
    }
    li:before {
       counter-increment: section;
       content: counters(section,".") " ";
    }
</style>
<ol>
    <li>a
        <ol>
            <li>b
            <li>c
        </ol>
    <li>d
</ol>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ov5f4rwf/

Comment: Great solution, only problem i have styling is not ok? http://jsfiddle.net/ov5f4rwf/1/

Comment: Add other styles as you need, but the main idea with putting numbers before `LI`s is in my post.

Comment: In li::before  i can get but the problem is to seperate

Comment: Nice can you update your question, also, on first item i want to remove 1 and on last? How to accomplish that, great mate you are the greatest

Comment: Also the problem is here when your have like 2.1

Comment: @play2web: what problem with `2.1` do you have? There is everything okay http://jsfiddle.net/ov5f4rwf/3/. What you want to remove? If you have st. like 3.1, there has to be 3. above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76607/discussion-between-play2web-and-panther).

Answer (score -1):

Is it okay to add span inside li like this https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7193/

```
.list-unstyled{
  padding-left: 25px;
}
.list-unstyled span{
  margin-left: -25px;
}
```

Comment: Putting number into manually isn't good idea. When you will have 100 `LI`s and you will want to put another one into top of the list, you'll manually change all other? The right way to make a typo :-)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, this is the first time I see "counter-reset" and "counter-increment" attributes from your answer. :-)